# Drawing from deck without replacement.

Tags: probability

Here's the initial question:

Audrey repeatedly draws cards from a standard $52$-card deck with replacement. Compute the expected number of draws for Audrey to get at least one card from each suit.

This is trivially the sum of Geometric RVs, and the solution is $\frac{25}{3}$

A less trivial question is the same question without replacement. Here's my thought process, and I am confident it is incorrect because the answer should definitely be less than $\frac{25}{3}$.

Let us define $X$ as the random variable representing the number of cards drawn until we get all $4$ suits. Let's define $Y = 52 - X$, where $Y$ represents the number of cards after we have drawn all $4$ suits.

$Y = I_1 + I_2 + ... + I_{52}$ where $I_j$ is the indicator denoting that card $j$ was drawn after all 4 suits had been drawn.

$E(Y) = E(I_1 + I_2 + ... + I_{52}) = E(I_1) + ... + E(I_{52})$

$E(I_j)$ is the probability that card $j$ was drawn after all 4 suits had been drawn.

Let $D_j$, $H_j$, $S_j$, and $C_j$ mean that a Diamond, Heart, Spade, and Club were drawn before card $j$.

$E(I_j) = P(D_j, H_j, S_j, C_j)$. This is where I may have gone wrong, but I think these events are independent. Whether a Diamond came before card $j$ shouldn't change whether a Club came before.

If this is true, we have $E(I_j) = P(D_j)P( H_j)P( S_j)P(C_j)$.

I will assume card $j$ is a Diamond. It shouldn't make a difference because of symmetry.

By this, we have $P(D_j)P( H_j)P( S_j)P(C_j) = P(D_j)P( H_j)^3$

$P(H_j)$ is the probability that card $j$ did not occur before all Hearts. This would be $\frac{13}{14}$. By symmetry, $j$ could be in any position, and being first has a probability of $\frac{1}{14}$.

$P(D_j)$ is the probability that card $j$ did not occur before all Diamonds, its own suit. This would be $\frac{12}{13}$. By symmetry, $j$ could be in any position, and being first has a probability of $\frac{1}{13}$.

Thus, we have $P(D_j)P( H_j)^3 = (\frac{12}{13})(\frac{13}{14})^3$.

Each $I_j$ has the same expectation, so $E(Y) = 52(\frac{12}{13})(\frac{13}{14})^3 = \frac{13182}{343}$.

Then $E(Y) = E(52 - X) = E(52) - E(X) = 52 - E(X)$, so $E(X) = 52 - \frac{13182}{343}$, which is approximately $13.56$.

Could someone help me observe where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but what I don't see accounted for is the fact that it is impossible to draw all four suits before 4 cards have been drawn.

Comment: I dont think they are independent since if we know none of diamond, heart or spade came before,  that will imply a club must have came?

Comment: @NinadMunshi agree with that statement, but I am not doing a traditional $E(X) =\sum_{i = 1} P_X(x) * x$, which would have probabilities 0 for $i = 1, ... 3$

Comment: @stochs not necessarily, card $j$ could just be the first card, right?

Comment: Aren't you summing over j?

Comment: @stochs summing over $j$? I am treating every card $j$ as its own, and getting the probability all 4 suits came before each card $j$. And it is equal for each $j$, so just multiplying by 52.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events $S_j,H_j,C_j$ and $D_j$ are dependent, and positively correlated.

Suppose that card number $j$ is the ace of spades. Then $\mathbb P(C_j)=1-1/14$. There are $14$ cards of interest, the thirteen clubs and the ace of spades, and each card is equally likely to appear first in the deck.

However,
$$
\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}
\P(C_j,D_j)=1-2/14+1/27
$$
This follows from the principle of inclusion exclusion. For the complementary event, either the ace of spades is before all the clubs, or the ace of spades is before all the diamonds. You add up the probabilities of these two, then subtract the probability of their intersection. The probability the ace of spades is before all clubs and all diamonds is $1/27$, by the same method. You can then check that $\P(C_j,D_j)>\P(C_j) \P(D_j)$, so the events are dependent.

When I originally wrote this answer, I had wrongly stated that the events were negatively correlated, using an intuitive argument. It just goes to show, we really cannot trust our intuition when it comes to probability!

---

Here is how I would approach the problem. Let $X$ be the number of cards you must draw, without replacement, to see all suits. We use the formula
$$
\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{x=1}^{52}\P(X\ge x)\tag1
$$
In order to compute $\P(X\ge x)$, use the principle of inclusion-exclusion. The event that {$X\ge x\}$ is equivalent to the event that there is at least one suit missing from the first $x-1$ cards. Let $A_x$ be the probability that spades are missing from the first $x$ cards, let $B_x$ be the same event but for hearts, then $C_x$ and $D_x$ for clubs and diamonds. The principle of inclusion exclusion implies that
$$
\begin{align}
\P(X\ge x)
  &=\P(\text{at least one suit missing from first $x-1$ cards})
\\&=\binom 41P(A_{x-1})-\binom 42P(A_{x-1},B_{x-1})\\
&\;\;\;+\binom43P(A_{x-1},B_{x-1},C_{x-1})-\binom44P(A_{x-1},B_{x-1},C_{x-1},D_{x-1})
\end{align}\tag2
$$

Some combinatorics shows that
$$
\begin{align}
P(A_{x-1})&={\binom{39}{x-1}/ \binom{52}{x-1}}
\\
P(A_{x-1},B_{x-1})&= {\binom{26}{x-1}/ \binom{52}{x-1}}
\\
P(A_{x-1},B_{x-1},C_{x-1})&={\binom{13}{x-1}/ \binom{52}{x-1}}
\\
P(A_{x-1},B_{x-1},C_{x-1},D_{x-1})&= {\binom{0}{x-1}/ \binom{52}{x-1}}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
The last expression looks a little funny, but it is correct. Note that $\P(A_0,B_0,C_0,D_0)=1$, because all of the suits are missing from the first zero cards. This agrees with the above, because $\binom00/\binom{52}{0}=1$. For any $x\ge 2$, we have $\binom{0}{x-1}=0$, so the probability is zero in all cases where $x \ge 2$, as expected (when you draw at least one card, you certainly see at least one suit).

Combining $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ leads to the answer. With the help of a Python script, I got a numerical value of $7.665$ for $E[X]$, which is indeed a bit less than $25/3$. This answer also agrees with simulation.

Comment: Your intuition is incorrect: $P(S_j \mid H_j) > P(S_j)$ because given there is at least one heart before card $j$, we have card $j$ further from the beginning of the deck.

Comment: Good catch! I fixed it and added some actual proof, so it should be correct now.